# OrientDB Create Edge between a Vertex and ODocument

Tags: graph, graph-databases, orientdb

I have a database with a whole bunch of ODocument records. They have their own Class hierarchy and it does not extend V.

I am in the process of adding in new collections and to support some of the features - we would like to use the graph db capabilities.

So I created a new Vertex per
`Vertex company = graph.addVertex(null);`

I find my existing ODoc and convert that to a vertex as

`Vertex person = null;
    for (Vertex v : graph.getVertices("Person.name", "Jay")) {
        person = v;
    }`

and try to create an Edge

```
Edge sessionInIncident = graph.addEdge(null, company, person, "employs");
```

The edge creation leads to the following

```
Class 'Person' is not an instance of V
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientElement.checkForClassInSchema(OrientElement.java:635)
at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientVertex.addEdge(OrientVertex.java:905)
at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientBaseGraph.addEdge(OrientBaseGraph.java:685)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to be a Vertex, class `Person` must extend the `V` class. Try this command:

```
alter class Person superclass V
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for!